# Typescript: Define type for multiple dynamic objects of object and append static objects with them

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have an object like this:

```
{
    mainObject:{
        object1:{
            data1:val,
            data2:val,
            data3:val
        },
        object2:{
            data1:val,
            data2:val,
            data3:val
        },
        object3:{
            data1:val,
            data2:val,
            data3:val
        },
        order:{
            0: object3,
            1: object2,
            2: object1
        },
        positions:{
            prev:{
                data1:val,
                data2:val,
                data3:val
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The points to take a note is:

1. The mainObject is an Object not Array.
2. These keys object1, object2 and object3 are dynamic, they can be anything and any limit(can be more than 3 or less).
3. keys order, positions are fixed keys they will come with data always.

Now my questions are:

1. How will we define type of this type of structure where we have objects in object and those objects keys are dynamic.
2. how will we append these 2 objects which are static with those dynamically set objects.

Some types i already set are:

```
interface ObjectVals {
  data1: string;
  data2: string;
  data3: string;
}

interface DynamicKeyVals {
  [key: string]: ObjectVals;
}
```

I have looked into many answers and documents but didn't get any relevant solution. can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
export type OrderType = {
    [T: number]: string
}

export type PositionType = {
    prev: {
        [T: string]: string
    }
}

export type CommonObjectType = {
    [T: string]: string
}

export type MainObjectStatic = {
    order: OrderType
    position: PositionType
}

export type MainObjectDynamic = {
    [T in string]: CommonObjectType
}

export type MainObject = MainObjectStatic | MainObjectDynamic

interface Wrapper {
    mainObject: MainObject
}

const a: Wrapper = {
    mainObject: {
        order: {
            1: "something"
        },
        position: {
            prev: {
                "data1": "value"
            }
        },
        object1: {
            value1: "value"
        },
        alma: {
            foo: "2"
        }
    },

}
```

However you can have a problem - it will allow you to implement only MainObjectStatic or MainObjectDynamic.

On the other hand, if you change to `export type MainObject = MainObjectStatic | MainObjectDynamic` it will point out a type incompatibility between `position` and `MainObjectDynamic`

I think mixing static and dynamic types at the same level will always be problematic - you should reorganize the structure if you can